# Arrow function alternative

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the arrow function alternative to this function ?

```
function(entry) {
  //
}(entry);
```

I tried some things like below, but it's not the correct way :

```
entry => {
   //
}(entry)
```

Comment: [MDN Web Docs: Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - Compare the two examples they provide, i.e., `function (a){
  return a + 100;
}` to `(a) => {
  return a + 100;
}`.

Comment: `(entry => {console.log(entry)})(12)`

Comment: This *is* the correct alternative. How did you test it? Why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: I talk about function call... not the inside return...

Comment: Again, your two pieces of code are *the same*. Both will work as function expressions. They cannot work when placed in a non-expression context but again, both will behave that way.

Comment: Typescript ask a ";" after the "}".

Comment: A linter error is not the same as "it doesn't work" but "it is not allowed by my style enforcing tool". The code works [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAnjAvDArAbgFB4AUAZgK5jBQCW4hCyKAlDAN54wyiQgA2cAdDxABzOolSN8AX0ZiGkgnNQYAfK3adwEXgKGj6E6bINM8QA) - if you have any rules that prevent compilation, you should have mentioned them. You can likely change your style enforcing rule.

Comment: Also, for completeness, neither the [normal function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAnjAvDArAbgFB4BmArmMFAJbgAUCyKAlDAN54wyiQgA2cAdNxABzWolQN8AX1H0JQA) nor the [arrow function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAnjAvDArAbgFB4LJroB8MA3njDKJCADZwB0DIA5gBRGoCU+AX26I+eIA) work when not placed in expression-only context.

Comment: You may need to wrap the functions in parentheses.

Comment: @ElectricShadow same thing with the normal function. It will not be a valid function declaration otherwise, so it will fail as well.

Comment: @ElectricShadow it's OK I need to wrap the functions with parentheses. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are mentioning [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
;(function (entry) {
  console.log(entry)
})("abc")

;((entry) => {
  console.log(entry)
})("def")
```

Comment: Notice the two things to learn from this answer are: 1) use parens to disambiguate what's being invoked, 2) don't invoke with the argument name, which is undefined outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the two examples provided at [**MDN Web Docs: Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

***Function styling...***

```
function (a){
   return a + 100;
}
```

***Arrow functions...***

```
(a) => {
   return a + 100;
}
```

Your code should then just work with...

```
entry => {
   //
}
```

As mentioned by others, your syntax is probably based on an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) statement.